# Python patch method from another module

Tags: python, monkeypatching, rethinkdb

I need to add some extra functionality to RethinkDB's `run()` method. Here's what I've come up with:

```
from rethinkdb.ast import RqlQuery

class ExtendedRqlQuery(RqlQuery):
    def run(self, c=None, **global_optargs):
        if not c:
            with connection.get_conn() as conn:
                return super(ExtendedRqlQuery, self).run(conn, **global_optargs)
        else:
            return super(ExtendedRqlQuery, self).run(c, **global_optargs)
RqlQuery = ExtendedRqlQuery
```

The problem is that, if I run a query without any connection parameter, the [default behavior](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/blob/next/drivers/python/rethinkdb/ast.py#L92) occurs, as if my patch didn't go into effect. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've put up a test and it seems very odd to me:

```
import rethinkdb as r
# Here is where I do my patching
import .utils

class Test(TestCase):
    def test(self):
        print r.ast.RqlQuery
        r.table('table').insert({'a': 1}).run()
```

The print statement says `<class 'remodel.utils.ExtendedRqlQuery'>` (which is right), but the following statement still uses the original file at `rethinkdb/ast.py`.

Comment: Where did the `connection` parameter come from?

Comment: It's a module written by me and imported some lines above.

Comment: Have you tried importing your `utils` first? Right now you have already imported the module before you're monkeypatching it somewhere else. Also you might have to set your monkeypatched module like `rethinkdb.ast.RqlQuery = ExtendedRqlQuery`.

Comment: I imported it first and it's the same thing. It is weird since the print statement says that it imported my patched class. Maybe the other methods (`table`, `insert`) get imported with the original class as super class, before I attempt to patch it?

Comment: As a workaround, could you instead implement your own Connection class with an overloaded _start() method? You could then register that connection as the repl connection, and calling the default run() on your query would simply call _start(self, optargs) on it.

Comment: `repl()` isn't thread safe so I cannot use it. I also have a pool of connections from which a connection should be picked only before running a query, then returned back to the pool right after the query has been executed.